# Change language at runtime in C# winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to change Language but when I compile this an exception pop up. it says

> "Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or
>   the neutral culture.  Make sure "System.Type.resources" was correctly
>   embedded or linked into assembly "mscorlib" at compile time, or that
>   all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed."

```
 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "English")
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("En");
            ChangeLanguage("En");
        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "German")
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("De");
            ChangeLanguage("De");
        }
    }


    private void ChangeLanguage(string lang)
    {
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            ComponentResourceManager resources = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Type));
            resources.ApplyResources(c, c.Name, new CultureInfo(lang));
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: In comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged put Console.Writeline(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()); so you can see where is the error

Comment: man this is gonna solve nothing ...

Comment: I know but I want know if the comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged is called in the formLoad

Comment: yes it is SettingsForm but what ever, its not in main form

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 ComponentResourceManager resources = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Type));
```

The argument to the constructor is wrong, you are telling it to find the resources for System.Type.  Which is why it is complaining that it can't find "System.Type.resources".  It will never find those.

You need to pass the type of the form that you actually want to localize.  Use `this.GetType()` instead.  Albeit that this probably will just localize your Options form and not the rest of the windows in your app.  You could iterate Application.OpenForms() instead.  It is also necessary to apply the localization to *all* the controls.  Not just the ones on the form, also the ones that are located inside containers like panels.  Thus:

```
    private static void ChangeLanguage(string lang) {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
        foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms) {
            localizeForm(frm);
        }
    }

    private static void localizeForm(Form frm) {
        var manager = new ComponentResourceManager(frm.GetType());
        manager.ApplyResources(frm, "$this");
        applyResources(manager, frm.Controls);
    }

    private static void applyResources(ComponentResourceManager manager, Control.ControlCollection ctls) {
        foreach (Control ctl in ctls) {
            manager.ApplyResources(ctl, ctl.Name);
            applyResources(manager, ctl.Controls);
        }
    }
```

Be careful with wiz-bang features like this.  Nobody actually changes their native language while they are using your program.

Comment: Thanks a lot! its working. And whats the most preferable approach to change the language if i may ask you.

Comment: If it is working then I gave you the most preferable approach.  If it is not then I'll pretend I don't know who wrote this code and say you're better off assuming that the user's default culture already matches his language :)  Kidding aside, I can't guarantee that it will work everywhere in the world.  It should, didn't test it that way.  Some day I'll figure out how neutral cultures work, that day is not yet close.

Comment: What happened to the lang argument that was passed into ChangeLanguage()?  I don't see it used anywhere.

Comment: The answer was based on the OP's snippet, note how he assigns Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture before calling ChangeLanguage().  After which the *lang* argument is not actually needed anymore.  I changed it to be a bit more logical.

Comment: @HansPassant There are a few problems in your function: Your function is just loop over the direct child controls of the form. It's not checking all the controls in controls hierarchy. For example controls which are hosted in containers like panel are not in `Controls` collection of the form. Your function is also missing components like `ContextMenu` which are not in `Controls` collection of the form. The function is treating all controls in the same way, while some controls need a custom logic. For a better solution take a look at this answer: https://www.stackoverflow.com/a/52179254/8684836

Comment: That's nonsense, applyResources() recurses and hits all the child controls.

Comment: @HansPassant I just reproduced your code in C++ CLR/CLI and it didn't work for `MenuStrip`, `ToolStripMenuItem` and its `DropDownItems`, only worked for labels and buttons though.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void ChangeLanguage(CultureInfo culture)
{
      Application.CurrentCulture = culture;
      CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
      CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;

      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture.Name);
      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture.Name);
}
```

You'll need to have appropriate resources for all languages though.

Comment: i got resx file with german version and englis is usid by default. sorry im newbie i dont get this culture  class much. just want to know why my code isnt working ...