# C# Localization from one Form for all other forms opened in the program

Tags: c#, winforms

to me, the question in the title seems like a regular thing one might do or have problems with, but I could not find anything on that matter.

I wrote a small program for a machine that I'm building and want to translate the UI-Elements, warning messages etc. into different languages. (German and English to start with). For that, I want to set the language in a "Settings"-form with a dropdown combobox.

I already found a working example on here how to do general localization of a form, and VisualStudio does not make it fairly difficult. How do I proceed from here? Do I need to pass some variable to the form I open, or can I set the language as a global variable and load it while opening other new forms.In total there are like 6 or 7 forms that will be opened and closed during usage.

Example code of two forms:

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class MES : Form
    {
        public MES()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Messen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add("English");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Deutsch");
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "English")
            {
                ChangeLanguage("en");
            }
            else
            {
                ChangeLanguage("de-DE");
            }
        }
        private void ChangeLanguage(string lang)
        {
            foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
            {
                ComponentResourceManager resources = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Messen));
                resources.ApplyResources(c, c.Name, new CultureInfo(lang));
            }
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NewForm NF = new NewForm();
            NF.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
}
```

Changing the label and button names in the MES Form does work, but nothing changes in the NF form (Localization is set to true there as well, and languages set accordingly).

Thanks for any hints and tips in advance.

Comment: I found the *easiest* way is to prompt the user with "to make this setting take effect, please restart the application" or something along that. Forcing a culture change during runtime is a PIA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change language at runtime in C# winform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067507/change-language-at-runtime-in-c-sharp-winform)

Comment: @Fildor what would PIA stand for and is that a bad thing? Closing the application for such change is a bit out of question for the way I imagine it.

Comment: PIA = three letter acronym for "Pain In [the] A$$" and yes, that's commonly seen as a rather unfortunate thing to encounter.

Comment: @ Fildor thanks for clearing that up =) Thought it would be an acronym regarding programming (which it kinda is in a wider sense). Have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below method . Source [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067507/change-language-at-runtime-in-c-sharp-winform)
  You can Pass this as reference in the localizeForm.

```
private static void localizeForm(Form frm) {
    var manager = new ComponentResourceManager(frm.GetType());
    manager.ApplyResources(frm, "$this");
    applyResources(manager, frm.Controls);
}

private static void applyResources(ComponentResourceManager manager, Control.ControlCollection ctls) {
    foreach (Control ctl in ctls) {
        manager.ApplyResources(ctl, ctl.Name);
        applyResources(manager, ctl.Controls);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks =) I came across the other post before, but seems like I overread the application for all forms. Got it working as I wanted.