# How to load a specific language XAML file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am building my language system using XAML files.

The code I have is as follows:

**es.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyAppTest"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <system:String x:Key="Hello">Hola</system:String>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**en.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyAppTest"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <system:String x:Key="Hello">Hello</system:String>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Name="en" Source="mylang/en.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Name="es" Source="mylang/es.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

**Main.xaml**

```
<TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource Hello}" />
<ComboBox>
   <ComboBoxItem Content="English" />
   <ComboBoxItem Content="Spanish" />
</ComboBox>
```

How can I read the language XAML file according to the language selected in the `ComboBox`?

Comment: Q: So you want to change the language dynamically, as your program executes, in response to changing the selection in your ComboBox.  Correct?

Comment: @paulsm4 yes, exactly that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change language at runtime in C# winform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067507/change-language-at-runtime-in-c-sharp-winform)

Comment: @paulsm4 I believe not because this link uses resx file and I'm using xaml

Comment: Dude - the point is that your *callback* needs modify CurrentUICulture property, call ComponentResourceManager.ApplyResources, etc. etc. The answer to your question involves *C# code*, not just XAML markup!  Your ComboBox has an event handler, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, my ComboBox has a handler event. But here it works differently from the resx file
In the app.xaml the last file added will always override the ones above
I want to know how I can read this specific xaml file to overlay what was read in the app.xaml

Comment: I'm frankly not sure what you're trying to do.  It sounds like maybe you're "reinventing the wheel".  Don't do that ;)  HOWEVER: 1) the "language" your UI renders should be determined by CurrentUICulture, 2) dynamically changing CurrentUICulture should be done in code - in a C# callback, invoked from your Xaml.  As far as internationalizing your Xaml: look here for the way Microsoft recommends: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/wpf-globalization-and-localization-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is possible by using `DynamicResource` like you did for `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource Hello}"/>
```

The `DynamicResource` markup extension will reslove a resource at runtime and update it if it was added, removed or replaced in a resource dictionary.  You would create a resource dictionary for each language and you would put them into the application resource dictionary.

Since you cannot assign multiple objects to the same key in a resource dictionary, you should only have the resource dictionary for the currently applied language in your application resources. Applying and switching languages is done in code by exchanging the current language resource dictionary.

In order to set the initial language, you can load your language setting and add the corresponding language resource dictionary to the application resources in the `App.xaml.cs` class. Use a URI and set it as source of the resource dictionary. I assume it is english in this sample.

```
var languageResourceDictionaryUri = new Uri("mylang/en.xaml");
var languageResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary { Source = languageResourceDictionaryUri };

Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(languageResourceDictionary);
```

You should store a reference to the current language resource dictionary, so you can remove it from the application resources, when the user changes the language using the `ComboBox`.

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(languageResourceDictionary);
```

Then you would add the a new resource dictionary for the selected language as above. Depending on where you want to switch the language, you might want to create a service to hide the access to the global, static application instance that is needed to change the resources.

Comment: thatguy - I think this is the right answer, but haven't you confused the issue by talking about current culture?  The question is about how to use different resources with the same key on a combobox change.  The OP doesn't mention culture or localization at all.

Comment: @RichN. You are right, this might be confusing the issue or may be out of the scope of the question, so I removed the remarks about culture.