# Windows Forms Localize resx without changing Culture

Tags: c#, winforms, multilingual, resx

I know it's easy to localize Windows Forms App: set Localizable=True, change Language and set text in Controls for every Language. This information saves in resx-files and application will automatically select the required file. Great!
I know about disadvantages of this solution (you need to rebuild the app if there a typo, it's impossible to change language in runtime, etc), but it's not a problem for me and "resources" is the simpliest, built-in solution.

But this mechanism uses the property Culture of app's thread.
My app is the part ("plugin") of the bigger application and works in the same Thread.
The main application is multilingual too, but it doesn't use Culture to change interface's language. I can change the thread's culture globally, but it crushes the main app's interface.

So my question:
is it possible to manually set the resx-localizable resurce file that will be used? Not based on Culture, but, for example, on some variable in my app:

```
if (this.Language == "fr")
    this.Resources.Add("Form1.fr.resx");
else
    this.Resources.Add("Form1.en.resx");
```

Or something else.

Thank you!

My sandbox:
https://github.com/Tereami/WindowsFormsTestLanguage

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21068497/17034

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built resources file has a property `ResourceManager` that's used to return the desired content. This has an overload with a `CultureInfo` parameter. You can use it to request resources in individual languages:

```
var desiredCulture = new CultureInfo("en-us");
var text = MyStrings.ResourceManager.GetString(nameof(Resources.ExitMessage), desiredCulture);
```

If you want to set the culture *globally* for your resource file, you could also set it through the corresponding property:

```
var desiredCulture = new CultureInfo("en-us");
MyStrings.Culture = desiredCulture;

var text = MyStrings.ExitMessage;
```

Comment: @RezaAghaei: Yes, the usual timing issue on SO. I was just slightly faster.  No answer for an hour and then two at the same time. 

Comment: Unfortunately it works only for MyStrings.resx (for the texts that I get manually). But I don't know how to set Culture for the Form1.resx file that automatically stores localizable values that I set in the form's Properties. Sorry for the late reply...

Comment: Currently I'm afk, but you should search for CurrentUICulture. If you set this, it should take the desired culture.

Comment: Do you mean CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture? It changes Culture for the whole Thread too...

Comment: I've found that I can set "Access modifier - Internal" for Form1.resx file and then I can set Form1.Culture as like as Mystrings.Culture. But then I catch the warning from VS about ambiguous names. If I manually change the name in the Form1.resx designer file, VS returns it back and the warning appeared again. Looks very strange